# Get a default value if no record exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql query which joins two tables.

```
   SELECT f.ProductSpecificationID, s.PropertyName, f.Value 
     FROM [LSCDATA].[ProductProperty] f 
LEFT JOIN [LSCMASTER].Property s 
       ON f.PropertyID=s.PropertyID
    WHERE s.PropertyName in ('spec_category','planning_method','inv_planning_method','so_source_type')
      AND f.ProductSpecificationID = 398431
 ORDER By ProductSpecificationID
```

and the results are displayed as below

```
ProductSpecificationID  PropertyName        Value
398431                  planning_method     MRP and MPP planning
398431                  so_source_type      INTERNAL
398431                  inv_planning_method Not planned
398431                  spec_category       GBPA Established
```

This is correct, since the record 398431 has four values for four properties.

But for record 398432, it has only three values for four properties,
and shows like, this record doesn't have `spec_category` property.

```
ProductSpecificationID  PropertyName        Value
398432                  planning_method     Not planned
398432                  so_source_type      INTERNAL
398432                  inv_planning_method Not planned
```

I just need a another row for `spec_category` with Value is null

```
ProductSpecificationID  PropertyName        Value
398432                  planning_method     Not planned
398432                  so_source_type      INTERNAL
398432                  inv_planning_method Not planned
398432                  spec_category       Null
```

Update #1:

I have created a SQLFiddle,

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a1bc4/4

I just need another row with only the Value for `spec_category` is Null

Comment: There is a method for that "COALESCE()" google it :)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hadn't understood the data structure.
Here you go:

```
  select spec.val 'ID',p.PropertyName,isnull(calc.val,'NA') 'Value'
        FROM 
            Property p
            CROSS JOIN (select distinct ProductSpecificationID from ProductProperty)spec(val)
            OUTER APPLY (select Value from ProductProperty pp  where pp.ProductSpecificationID=spec.val and pp.PropertyID=p.PropertyID) calc(val)
        ORDER By spec.val
```

Comment: Wow, you are a genius. This works. Until now, I never heard that there is an operator called Apply. Thanks a lot @George.

Comment: apply is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

To get true `LEFT JOIN` result, move the right side table condition from `WHERE` to `ON`.

To get NA instead of null, use `COALESCE()`.

```
SELECT f.ProductSpecificationID, COELESCE(s.PropertyName, 'NA'), f.Value
FROM [LSCDATA].[ProductProperty] f 
LEFT JOIN [LSCMASTER].Property s ON f.PropertyID = s.PropertyID
AND s.PropertyName in
    ('spec_category','planning_method','inv_planning_method','so_source_type')
ORDER BY ProductSpecificationID
```

Comment: This will only bring 1 column if there are 0; it won't return 4 rows if there are 3.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis, perhaps you're right. I'll wait and see if OP makes the problem clearer before I do any changes,

Answer (score 0):

Generate all the rows you want with a `cross join`, then use `left join` to bring in the existing values:

```
SELECT ps.ProductSpecificationID, 
       v.PropertyName,
       f.Value
FROM (VALUES ('spec_category'), 
             ('planning_method'), 
             ('inv_planning_method'),
             ('so_source_type')
     ) v(PropertyName) CROSS JOIN
     (SELCT DISTINCT f.ProductSpecificationID
      FROM [LSCDATA].[ProductProperty] f 
     ) ps LEFT JOIN
     [LSCMASTER].Property s
     ON s.PropertyID = ps.PropertyID AND
        s.PropertyName = v.PropertyName
ORDER BY ps.ProductSpecificationID
```